# Interpretation of Durbin-Watson-Test in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpretation, autocorrelation, durbin-watson-test

I receive the following results of a Durbin-Watson test in R.

```
lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value
1       0.7302306     0.5348529    0.00
2       0.4735212     1.0428875    0.00

Alternative hypothesis: rho[lag] != 0
```

does it mean, Null hypothesis is rejected and residuals are not autocorrelated as D-W statistic is <2?

Comment: Welcome to CV. This is a great question. Which command did you use? Did you use the lmtest package or the car package or another one?

Comment: > durbinWatsonTest(lmH20, max.lag=12, simulate=TRUE, alternative="positive")

Comment: sorry, I used car package of durbinWatsonTest() function

Comment: @Ferdi, did you just create a new tag [tag:durbin-watson-test]? Are you going to add a tag description and excerpt? I would be careful about creating new tags just like that.

Comment: @RichardHardy Okay. Sorry. What is the official way of creating a new tag?

Comment: @Ferdi, I am not an expert in that, and frankly I just don't know. I suggest you consult Meta CV or Meta SE. But one thing I try to avoid and get rid of are tags without descriptions, duplicate tags, etc. We should try to keep some order when it comes to tags.

Comment: @Ferdi, now that there is a Wiki and an excerpt (thank you for that! Though be more careful next time and try to formulate those as precisely as possible), what about the older posts (144 of them) that mention the Durbin-Watson test? Would you kindly check the protocol how these should be treated when a new tag is created?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you. It is almost 11pm in Germany. So I will do it tomorrow. Actually "Durbin-Watson" would be a better name than "Durbin-Watson" test because it would also cover the "Durbin-Watson" test statistic. Is it possible to change the name of the tag?

Comment: @Ferdi, I don't know if it is possible to edit tag names, but the current one *does* cover both the Durbin-Watson test and the Durbin-Watson test statistic, so there is probably no need to change it.